# Decide whether or not the following improper integral exists

Tags: calculus, analysis

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} \,dx $$

Hello I need your advice. This problem was in my Math Homework. Now look what I did

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}  \int_{0}^{R} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} \, dx  $$

I calculated the Integral of this function:
$$ \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} \,dx = ln|\sqrt{1+x} -1| + ln|\sqrt{1+x} +1 | +c   $$

$$ \int_{0}^{R} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} \, dx = ln|\sqrt{1+R} -1| + ln|\sqrt{1+R} +1| - ln2  $$

$$  \lim_{R\to\infty}  ln|\sqrt{1+R} -1| + ln|\sqrt{1+R} +1| - ln2 = \infty  $$

So can I say that this improper integral exists ? and why?

Comment: I would worry more about $\int_{0}^{R}$ than $\int_{R}^{\infty}$

Comment: You haven't evaluated correctly $\int_0^R$: it should have been $$\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+R}-1\rvert+\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+R}+1\rvert-\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+0}-1\rvert+\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+0}+1\rvert=\\=\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+R}-1\rvert+\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+R}+1\rvert+\ln2+\infty$$

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} \,dx = \ln|\sqrt{1+x} -1| - \ln|\sqrt{1+x} +1 | +c$ (you had a sign error) and you should consider $\int\limits_r^R \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} \,dx$ as $r\searrow 0^+$ and $R \nearrow +\infty$.  The limit of the definite integral is $+\infty$, as you say, caused by $r\searrow 0^+$

Comment: @Henry Why do you need $\searrow$ while you also have $0^+$ (the plus sign) or vice versa. (I am just curious, we don't use this notation, thanks)

Comment: @VIVID No good reason.  I used one then misread what I had written so added the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it into two
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}} dx$$

- The second one converges since $x\sqrt{1+x} \sim x^{3/2}$ when $x\to\infty$.
- The first integral diverges since $x(1+x)^{1/2} \sim x\left(1+\frac12 x\right) \sim x$ as $x\to 0$.